# Array length in Javascript chrome error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a very strange problem with js console in chrome,
if i go in chrome console and write :

```
var numero = new Array(["/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"]);
```

return me "undefined" so i think numero is an array with 2 elements, but if i write:

```
numero
```

returns:

```
[Array[2]]
```

after

```
numero.length
```

and return 1 ..... why? don't return 2 ???
where am I doing wrong?
can i give a method that returns 2? 
thanks in advance

EDIT:
I will explain my problem.
I have a function that return this when i selected 2 items :

```
myFolders.getSelected()
["/php/.svn", "/php/upload.php"]
```

and this when selected one items:

```
myFolders.getSelected()
"/php/upload.php"
```

as u note the second one isn't an array.

now i use this method to activate on change selected item an calculate a global variable:

```
function calcoloNumeroElementi(){
    var numero = new Array(myFolders.getSelected());
    numeroElementiSelezionati = numero[0].length;
}
```

but returns always 1 or the number of characters when i selected only one items.

Comment: Don't do `new Array(['fdsf','dfsfd']);`, leave out the `[` and `]`, just do `new Array('sdfdsfsd','fsdfsdfs');` instead

Comment: Your `.getSelected()` method is *returning an array*; no reason to wrap it's return value in `new Array()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use New Array, use just literal notation:

```
var numero = ["/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"];
```

*Update (Based on your comments)*

If you have your function `myFolders.getSelected()` that returns a single string and you want to add it to array, you can do this either declaratively:

```
var numero = [myFolders.getSelected()]
```

Or, if you plan to add multiple values, e.g. in a loop, you can push new value into array

```
var numero = [];
...
numero.push(myFolders.getSelected());
```

Comment: yes but try this
`var numero = myFolders.getSelected();
undefined
numero
"/php/.svn/tmp"
numero.length
13`

Comment: What's `myFolders.getSelected();` ? If it returns String, then "numero.length" will return that String's length in characters, this time Arrays are not involved

Comment: @r1si added possible code variation based on assumption that `myFolders.getSelected()` returns a string. If it returns other types, please specify

Answer (score 6):

You're creating an `array` inside other `array`, that's why it returns 1.

```
console.log( numero[0].length ); // 2
```

So it should be:

```
var numero = ["/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"];
```

or

```
var numero = new Array("/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"); // without `[` and `]`
```

Then use `console.log( numero.length );`

Comment: work like a claim for 2 elements: return 2 
but with only one elements array dont work .... return the number of chararpters

Comment: @r1si Use `console.log( numero.length );` after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

`["/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"]` returns an array containing the two strings.

`new Array(arg0, arg1 ... argn);` returns an array with the elements defined as the arguments

`new Array(["/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"]);` will return an array where the first elements is and array of two strings.

Try instead `numero[0].length` and see what you get.

Or istead define your array just like this `var numero = ["/php/.svn/tmp", "/php/.svn/props"];`